# Laravel validation required_if is not working

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have the email and password fields in which I only want them to be required if the `add_user` field value is `1`. This is my validation:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'add_user' => ['required'],
        'password' => ['required_if:add_user,1', 'min:8'],
        'email' => ['required_if:add_user,1', 'email', 'max:255'],
    ];
}
```

This one is not working, it always errors even if the value is 0. I fill out the `add_user` value using jquery. I have a drop down that if the user clicked from the options, `add_user` value is 0, but if thru input, value is 1. Values are correct but the validation isn't working. Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Got it.

I added a nullable validation property and now it works.

```
return [
    'add_user' => ['required'],
    'password' => ['required_if:add_user,1', 'min:8', 'nullable'],
    'email' => ['required_if:add_user,1', 'email', 'max:255', 'nullable'],
];
```

Hope this will help someone, someday.

Answer (score 0):

We are checking two fields that are not dependent to each other means if `user_id!=1` there will be some other validation on password and email so we need to check it by this way

```
     $rules = [
           'type' => 'required'
         ];

     $v = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

     $v->sometimes('password', 'required|min:8', function($input) {
          return $input->type == '1';
     });
```

Here we make an instance of `Validator` where we checking password is required if `user_id ==1` else we no need to validate it.

In Model you can do this.

```
 public function rules(){
    return [
      'user_id '     => 'required'
    ];
 }

 protected function getValidatorInstance() {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();
        $validator->sometimes('password', 'required|min:8', 
            function($input) {
            return $input->user_id== 1;
        });
        return $validator;
    }
```

Comment: Check i have made some changes to it,